# How to limit database usage by Azure WebJob

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-webjobs

My web app an Azure has a WebJob (dnx console app). This WebJob runs periodically and loads new products to database (millions). This results in a 100% database usage. The actual application is blocked.

Is there a way to limit this WebJob's resources to say 50%?

Comment: So you load millions of products each time the job is running ? Are you loading all the products ?

Comment: @Thomas Actually I'm synchronizing them. The code is quite optimized, it all happens on database side. `MERGE` command figures out which products should be added, updated or removed. Anyway it's not the case. I'd just like the WebJob to do it's job without rush, and without consuming all the resources.

Comment: Are you using Sql Server ? An SSIS package could be another approach

Comment: @Thomas I'm using Azure SQL

Comment: So you don't have access the db VM ?